# How to index data in a specific shard using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am using solrj as client to index documents into solr cloud (Using solr4.5)

I had a requirement to save documents based on tenant_id, so i am trying to do **document routing**. Which is possible only if the collection is created using **numShards** parameter (http://searchhub.org/2013/06/13/solr-cloud-document-routing/)

I have two instances of solr in solr cloud(example1/solr and example2/solr) and exrenal zookeeper which is running in 2181 port.

Both the instances consist collection called **collection1**

I created one more collection called **newCollection**(With two shards and two replicas) using 
 `http://localhost:8501/solr/admin/collectionsaction=CREATE&name=newCollection&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&router.field=id`

So in example1/solr-> I have newCollection_shard1_replica1 & newCollection_shard2_replica1,

In example2/solr -> I have newCollection_shard1_replica2 & newCollection_shard2_replica2

I copied example1/solr/collection1/conf to all shards and replicas

**I restarted zookeeper server as well as solr instances:**

zookeeper->zkServer.cmd

example1/solr-> java -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/newCollection_shard1_replica1/conf -Dcollection.configName=myconf -DzkHost=localhost:2181 -jar start.jar

example2/solr->java -DzkHost=localhost:2181 -jar start.jar

(Both instances are running at different port, one is at 8081 and other at 8051)

---

I am using solrj client to index documents

Here is my sample code

```
String url="http://localhost:8081/solr"
ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer solrServer= new ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer(url, 10000, 4);
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "shard1!513");
doc.addField("name", "Santhosh");
solrServer.add(documents);
solrServer.commit();
```

But it is saving document in **collection1** with id shard1!513, is there any configuration changes required in solrconfig.xml (I am using default solrconfig.xml which came with solr4.5)

How to save documents in my **newCollection**? and how to do document routing?

Please help me out with issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appended Core name of new Collection to the URL. so it is working fine now.

Instead of:

```
String url="http://localhost:8081/solr"
```

I used:

```
String url="http://localhost:8081/solr/newCollection_shard1_replica1"
ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer solrServer= new ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer(url, 10000, 4);
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "shard1!513");
doc.addField("name", "Santhosh");
solrServer.add(documents);
solrServer.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use CloudSolrServer and UpdateRequest

```
SolrServer solrServer = new CloudSolrServer(zkHost) // zkHost is your solr zookeeper host string
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
UpdateRequest add = new UpdateRequest();
add.add(document);
add.setParam("collection", "newCollection");
add.process(solrServer);

UpdateRequest commit = new UpdateRequest();
commit.setAction(UpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
commit.setParam("collection", "newCollection");
commit.process(solrServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CloudSolrServer http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrServer.html

Because in solrcloud, updates must be routed via zookeeper, as zookeeper knows the status of leaders in cloud.One more thing you need not to append collection name to url, just use setDefaultCollection(collectionName); method of CloudSolrServer to send your updates to 'collectionName' collection