# Adding Data to a particular core in multicore solr instance

Tags: solr

I have done the following steps to create a **multicore** setup of **Solr**.

I have a **Solr** instance running on **Jetty** (I have used the default configurations).

I have copied 1 core to another,

1) Now in this scenario. if I run the post.jar command to add a document to an index, then will it be added to **both** cores?
2) So if I query the **Solr** index then which core will fetch the result?
3) Which command should I use to post a new document for indexing in a particular core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you shard it or was it replicated? Read [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Nodes,+Cores,+Clusters+and+Leaders) if you don't know. 1) Either [sharding](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding) or replicated are synchronized internally by solr, so it should be divided or added in both cores. 2) It doesn't matter which one, solr does that for you, you just need to have zooKeeper ready to accept and balance requests between each core. 3) You can't if your're adding data to a core that is replicated, but if you're sharding cores I think it's possible, it was answered here: [How to index data in a specific shard using solrj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479081/how-to-index-data-in-a-specific-shard-using-solrj)

Comment: Thanks . I had replicated the core.